# elements that don't factor uniquely

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers

> With proof, list all of the elements $z \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6} i]$ with $\lVert z \rVert \leq 10$ that do not factor uniquely (here $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the magnitude of a complex number).

I think the elements are $\pm 6, \pm 10, \pm 6 \pm 2\sqrt{6} i, \pm 6 \pm 3 \sqrt{6} i, \pm 4\sqrt{6}i, \pm 2 \pm 4\sqrt{6}i.$ It's not hard to show that these elements don't factor uniquely up to order and associates; for instance, $6 = 2 \cdot 3 = (\sqrt{6} i) (-\sqrt{6}i)$ and clearly $\pm \sqrt{6} i, 2, 3$ are nonunits but non are associates of each other. Also, $2 + 4\sqrt{6} i = (-2 + \sqrt{6} i) (2 - \sqrt{6} i) = 2(1+2\sqrt{6} i), \\10 = 2\cdot 5 = (2+\sqrt{6} i) (2-\sqrt{6} i), \\
6+2\sqrt{6} i = 2(3 + \sqrt{6}i) = (\sqrt{6}i)(2-\sqrt{6}i)\\
6+3\sqrt{6} i = 3(2+\sqrt{6}i) = (\sqrt{6}i)(3-\sqrt{6}i)\\
4\sqrt{6}i = 2(2\sqrt{6}i)=4(\sqrt{6}i)\\
.$

> But how do I show that these are the only such elements? There are $126$ nonzero nonunits in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6} i]$ with $\lVert z\rVert \leq 10$, so would I literally have to check all distinct elements up to order and associates (this reduces the number, but it's still very tedious)?

> Edit: Sorry about the other typo; I indeed meant to type $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}i]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}i]$.

Comment: I don't think this solves the whole problem, but if the norm of the number is prime number, then it is irreducible. This allows you to rule out some more possibilities.

Comment: Why would $\sqrt{6}i$ be in your ring?

Comment: @CaptainLama fixed.